# How to capture video/screenshot of android device

Tags: android, screenshot, video-capture

Is there any application which can take video/screenshot of android device. I know there are few softwares for capturing screen's video/image in desktop like camtasia, snagit.

Is there anything available similar for Android device?

I know way to capture screen image using DDMS, but what if user is not having android sdk available with him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

It could possibly be done with a rooted phone but would require specific software. But in this case it would be 'what if a user doesn't have a rooted phone'.

The Android API doesn't include anything which allows writing 'screen-shot' applications natively.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing with screenshots

Users can now share what's on their screens more easily by taking screenshots. Hardware buttons let them snap a screenshot and store it locally. Afterward, they can view, edit, and share the screen shot in Gallery or a similar app**

Will be possible in Android Ice cream sandwich version